# Show/Hide div with scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, show-hide

I know the title isn't the most descriptive and there are many more topics with similar questions like this, but I couldn't find any answers. In fact, I got this far thanks to you guys so, here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a DIV that I want to show when the page is scrolled to a certain position (trigger), marked by *#othdiv*. This DIV disappears when you scroll further down to the next position (trigger) marked as *#othdiv2*.

This feels like it's a very simple solution but I just can't figure it out. I have tried conditional if statements, duplicating codes, removing lines, new variables... sigh... please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
var topOfOthDiv2 = $("#othdiv2").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        $("#dvid").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
        else
    if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?                
        $("#dvid").hide(); //reached the desired point -- show div            
    }           
    });
});
```

Current code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/124/

Bottom line:
I'm trying to do something similar to this: http://mailchimp.com/2012/   (notice the titles [the app, support, operations, etc])

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/125/)

Comment: You guys are awesome! Now, if I could abuse of your kindness:

How would I add a 'buffer' to the topOfthDiv. Meaning, right now the div hides/shows when the scroll touches the div. How can I do it so that it toggles only after, for example, 200px AFTER scrolling past the div.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Aha, I added a `position:relative;top:200px;` to othdiv, and problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `&&` as in: if (this and that){do something} else{don't}

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/DnJ2z/127/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
    var topOfOthDiv2 = $("#othdiv2").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv && $(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv2) {
            $("#dvid").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvid").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

For a much better explanation of logical operators check out: [Logical Operators MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with your fiddle and manage to get it working. Check if it's what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
    var topOfOthDiv2 = $("#othdiv2").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv && $(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv2) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#dvid").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
            else
        if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv || $(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv2)    { //scrolled past the other div?                
            $("#dvid").hide(); //reached the desired point -- show div            
        }           
    });
});
```